# How to get highlighted text (String) in MuPdf?

Tags: android, mupdf

I am using MuPdf to display pdf file and its successfully implemented but now i want to get selected (highlighted) text?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me you have 2 problems, the first is to extract the text, which MuPDF can already do. There is example code for this I believe. Then you need to compare the co-ordinates of the highlighted area with the position of the text, and decide which text is within the highlighted area.

So the first part you have example code for, the second part is up to you, as its (presumably) your application that draws the highlight. THe last part is then your job, figure out which text is within the area.